# Что такое многомодульность?

Tags: java, android, модули

Дорогие коллеги. Подскажите, пожалуйста, определение понятия многомодульность. Что это и зачем оно нужно? В процессе поиска, ни одного хотя бы внятного объяснения этого термина, мне найти не удалось. Большое спасибо!

Comment: Кроме уменьшения [связности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Зацепление_(программирование)) кода между модулями, с помощью многомодульности можно [ускорить](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FMiFtsew2UY) сборку приложения. В андроид часто под многомодульностью понимают разделение на gradle-модули. Отдельные gradle-модули могут собираться независмо друг от друга, параллельно на разных процессорах, тем самым уменьшится скорость сборки андроид-проекта.

Answer (score 2):

1. В терминах Java 9 модуль это совокупность пакетов, по сути следующий уровень иерархии: `класс-пакет-модуль`. Модуль в Java 9 описывается файлом `module-info.java`, который лежит обычно в корне самого модуля.
2. В терминах IDE модуль это часть проекта (если угодно подпроект), в Intellij IDEA или Android Studio он так и называется *module*, обычно оформляется в виде отдельного дерева каталогов/исходников и содержит в себе либо отдельный `build.gradle` или `pom.xml` или `module.iml` (в зависимости от системы сборки).